# $13$ is the largest prime that can divide two successive integers of the form $n^2+3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I prove following problem in number theory?

> Show that $13$ is the largest prime that can divide two successive integers of the form $n^2+3$.

Comment: Please show your working so far. It'll help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p=4k+1$ is a prime number and $q$ is another prime number such that
$$q|n^2+k, q|(n+1)^2+k$$
which implies that $q|2n+1$.
Now note that
$$4(n^2+k)=(2n+1)(2n-1)+4k+1$$
because $q|4(n^2+k)$ and $q|(2n+1)(2n-1)$, $q|4k+1=p$ and $q=p$. (In your question $k=3$).

Comment: Nice perspective, but how can we be sure it is only possible for k=3 meaning 13 is the largest prime to have this property?

Comment: $5$ is the largest prime that can divide two successive integers of the form $n^2+1$. $17$ is the largest prime that can divide two successive integers of the form $n^2+4$.

Comment: Wonderful! Learned about the whole picture. My heart is glowing with the beauty! Pardon if my excitement is different here, it's just so beautiful!